# Nuxt 3 useCookie composable not being created when adding domain or expire options

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

https://nuxt.org.cn/api/composables/use-cookie/

I'm trying to use the nuxt3 composable useCookie to store data like the selected language to display the page.

to create the cookie i would have something like

```
<script setup lang="ts"> 
const language = useCookie(   'language',
   { default: () => 'english'}
)  

</script> 
<template>  </template>
```

in this case all works as expected the cookie is created nad can be used later.

now the problem is if I want to add a domain or maxAge it would become something like this :

```
const language = useCookie(   'language',
   { default: () => 'english',
    domain: 'http://localhost:4000/'}
)
```

now in this case the cookie is never created and cannot be used to get or store data.

I have no idea that's going wrong if someone could help it would be a life saver.